# sysdate difference ( how to make query between sysdate and my table date)

Tags: oracle

I am new to oracle.

I have some problems to make query.

Im trying to make query that solves the difference between sysdate() and the date from my own table

```
select to_char(to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')   
        - to_char(S_DATE||S_HOUR||':00' , 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')) 
from dual;
```

I'm doing like that.

In my table, I have two columns `'S_DATE'` and `'S_HOUR'` that means time.

So, I would like to know the time difference and how to make this query.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: why not just store your date as a date? then no conversions necessary. just subtract the two values. a thing folks new to Oracle usually don't get right is dates. A DATE is the point in time - so day & time. always store dates as dates, never as numbers or strings.

Comment: you can not "subtract" one varchar from another. You need to use *real* `date` values. Get rid of the `to_char()` on sysdate and use `to_date()` on your table columns to convert them to a proper `date` value.

Answer (score 2):

You can get difference between two dates by simple - (minus) operator. However first you need to convert date string to date using `TO_DATE`.

Sample in SQL Fidlle is [**here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/74b7c6/15/0)

The sample query:

```
select 
sysdate , S_DATE || ' ' || S_HOUR "Date",
round((sysdate - to_date(s_date || s_hour ,' YYYY/MM/DDHH24:MI') ) * 24 * 60, 2)  "Dif In Min",
round((sysdate - to_date(s_date || s_hour ,' YYYY/MM/DDHH24:MI') ) * 24 * 60 * 60, 2)  "Dif In Sec"
from myDate
```